# Jenkins + Github Pull Request builder display name

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For our project we use GitHub. We have TravicCI enabled (as this was required for our project to use). Besides that, we've also got a full instance of Jenkins running with the pull request builder.

Now this all works fine, and in the overview of a pull request this looks like this:
[image: Overview pull request]

Now as you can see travis is displayed nicely with a name. The Jenkins setup is however shown as 'default'. I'd like to change this to something else, however I can not find anything anywhere (github, jenkins, plugin settings) on how/where to change this. How do I change this?

Answer (score 29):

You can change this in the job.

Your Job > Configure > Build Triggers > Trigger Setup > Commit Status Context

Enter something in this field to override "default".

Comment: "Commit Status Context" looks promising.  However, it is not working in GHPRB 1.29.  The context is created for the _Build Triggered_ action but not to the other "Commit Status" actions.

Comment: @jmoody, that's what I'm seeing as well. Did you find a fix? Or are you still getting 'default' for everything except the Build Triggered action?

Comment: It looks like if you rely on the default settings for the plugin, you end up with this behavior. If you set the `Context` in the build settings specifically, it seems to work as intended.

Comment: @MikeCole setting the individual job's `Commit Status Context` field worked for me. I have two GHPRB configurations using this that run on each PR, and they behave almost identically however the second one does not get a "Details" link, and I'm not sure why yet.

Comment: @meowsqueak (and mostly for posterity) Make sure you're using `Build Triggers > GHPRB > Trigger Setup... > Update commit status during build > Commit Status Context` *not* the `Post-build Actions > Set GitHub commit status (universal) > Commit Status Context`

Answer (score 4):

In the GHPRB ver 1.33.0, the option for changing the name of the check for GitHub PR is within the job configuration:
Your Job > Configure > Build Environment > Set GitHub commit status with custom context and message (Must configure upstream job using GHPRB trigger) > Commit Status Context

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to this answer, but my suggestion is to create another user as a 'bot' account to connect with GitHub from your Jenkins server instead of using your main admin account. This adds another security layer to the connection. I wrote a bit about it [here](https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210)