# How can I rename Jenkins' pull request builder's "status check" display name on GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github

We have a project on **GitHub** which has two **Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline** jobs - one **builds** the project and the other runs **tests**. The only difference between these two pipelines is that they have different **JenkinsFiles**.

I have two problems that I suspect are related to one another:

1. In the GitHub status check section I only see one check with the following title: 
   `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge — This commit looks good`,
   which directs me to the **test** Jenkins pipeline. This means that our **build** pipeline is not being picked up by GitHub even though it is visible on Jenkins. I suspect this is because both the checks have the same name (i.e. `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`).
2. I have not been able to figure out how to rename the status check message for each Jenkins job (i.e. **test** and **build**). I've been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352818/jenkins-github-pull-request-builder-display-name) similar question, but its solution wasn't applicable to us as **Build Triggers** aren't available in **Multibranch Pipelines**

If anyone knows how to change this message on a per-job basis for *Jenkins Multibranch Pipelines* that'd be super helpful. Thanks!

*Edit (just some more info):*

We've setup GitHub/Jenkins webhooks on the repository and builds do get started for both our **build** and **test** jobs, it's just that the status check/message doesn't get displayed on GitHub for both (only for **test** it seems).
Here is our JenkinsFile for for the **build** job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy 
properties([[$class: 'BuildConfigProjectProperty', name: '', namespace: '', resourceVersion: '', uid: ''], buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')), [$class: 'ScannerJobProperty', doNotScan: false]])
node {
    stage('Initialize') {
        echo 'Initializing...'
        def node = tool name: 'node-lts', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
        env.PATH = "${node}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }

    stage('Checkout') {
        echo 'Getting out source code...'
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Install Dependencies') {
        echo 'Retrieving tooling versions...'
        sh 'node --version'
        sh 'npm --version'
        sh 'yarn --version'
        echo 'Installing node dependencies...'
        sh 'yarn install'
    }

    stage('Build') {
        echo 'Running build...'
        sh 'npm run build'
    }

    stage('Build Image and Deploy') {
        echo 'Building and deploying image across pods...'
        echo "This is the build number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        // sh './build-openshift.sh'
    }

    stage('Upload to s3') {
        if(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master"){
            withAWS(region:'eu-west-1',credentials:'****') {
                def identity=awsIdentity();
                s3Upload(bucket:"****", workingDir:'build', includePathPattern:'**/*');
                cfInvalidate(distribution:'EBAX8TMG6XHCK', paths:['/*']);
            }
        };
        if(env.BRANCH_NAME == "PRODUCTION"){
            withAWS(region:'eu-west-1',credentials:'****') {
                def identity=awsIdentity();
                s3Upload(bucket:"****", workingDir:'build', includePathPattern:'**/*');
                cfInvalidate(distribution:'E6JRLLPORMHNH', paths:['/*']);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162309/10721592) answer?

Comment: I had a look at it but it didn't seem to fit into our JenkinsFile structure. We're running a node project so I don't know if the files will be different. I'll add a copy of our JenkinsFile to the question so you can have a look at it - I have very little experience with JenkinsFiles, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Replied in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `GitHubCommitStatusSetter` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214730/how-to-set-github-commit-status-with-jenkinsfile-not-using-a-pull-request-builde/47162309#47162309) answer for declarative pipeline syntax). You're using a scripted pipeline syntax, so in your case it will be something like this (note: this is just prototype, and it definitely must be changed to match your project specific):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy 
properties([[$class: 'BuildConfigProjectProperty', name: '', namespace: '', resourceVersion: '', uid: ''], buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '5')), [$class: 'ScannerJobProperty', doNotScan: false]])
node {

    // ...

    stage('Upload to s3') {
        try {
            setBuildStatus(context, "In progress...", "PENDING");

            if(env.BRANCH_NAME == "master"){
                withAWS(region:'eu-west-1',credentials:'****') {
                    def identity=awsIdentity();
                    s3Upload(bucket:"****", workingDir:'build', includePathPattern:'**/*');
                    cfInvalidate(distribution:'EBAX8TMG6XHCK', paths:['/*']);
                }
            };

            // ...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            setBuildStatus(context, "Failure", "FAILURE");
        }
        setBuildStatus(context, "Success", "SUCCESS");
    }
}

void setBuildStatus(context, message, state) {
  step([
      $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
      contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: context],
      reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: "https://github.com/my-org/my-repo"],
      errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
      statusResultSource: [ $class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: message, state: state]] ]
  ]);
}
```

Please check [this](https://gist.github.com/jonico/e205b16cf07451b2f475543cf1541e70) and [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39482?focusedCommentId=288123&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-288123) links for more details.

Comment: I'll try this out and report back. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I just tried this and it works! I can even set up checks for each stage in my pipeline which is super useful! Thanks for all the help @biruk1230. Resolved

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Sadly this solution stopped working for me today. I keep getting a 
"ERROR: [GitHub Commit Status Setter] - Cannot retrieve Git metadata for the build, setting build result to UNSTABLE"
error message every time I run the `setBuildStatus` method. I've tried [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54249?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) solution but it did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: If you already downgraded **GitHub** plugin, try to downgrade also **GitHub Branch Source** plugin, because seems to be that it's the issue with plugin updates.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Github Custom Notification Context SCM Behaviour` plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-scm-trait-notification-context/

> After installing go to the job configuration. Under "Branch sources" -> "GitHub" -> "Behaviors" click "Add" and select "Custom Github Notification Context" from the dropdown menu. Then you can type your custom context name into the "Label" field.

Comment: Thank you! It is great that there is a plugin to support changing the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is pretty much like @biruk1230's answer. But if you don't want to downgrade your github plugin to work around the bug, then you could call the API directly.

```
void setBuildStatus(String message, String state) 
{
    env.COMMIT_JOB_NAME = "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge/sanity-test"
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'github-token', variable: 'TOKEN')]) 
    {
        // 'set -x' for debugging. Don't worry the access token won't be actually logged
        // Also, the sh command actually executed is not properly logged, it will be further escaped when written to the log
        sh """
            set -x
            curl \"https://api.github.com/repos/thanhlelgg/brain-and-brawn/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT?access_token=$TOKEN\" \
                -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \
                -X POST \
                -d \"{\\\"description\\\": \\\"$message\\\", \\\"state\\\": \\\"$state\\\", \
                \\\"context\\\": \\\"${env.COMMIT_JOB_NAME}\\\", \\\"target_url\\\": \\\"$BUILD_URL\\\"}\"
        """
    } 
}
```

The problem with both methods is that `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge` will be displayed no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful with @biruk1230's answer.
You can remove Jenkins' status check which named `continuous-integration/jenkins/something` and add custom status check with `GitHubCommitStatusSetter`. It could be similar effects with renaming context of status check.

Install [Disable GitHub Multibranch Status](https://plugins.jenkins.io/disable-github-multibranch-status/) plugin on Jenkins.
This can be applied by setting `behavior` option of Multibranch Pipeline Job on Jenkins.

Thanks for your question and other answers!